# Post form to a different/external domain or url in Meteor

Tags: javascript, forms, post, meteor

I basically wanted to implement a payment mechanism in my Meteor app using a payment service provider but the information has to be posted in their url as the data are very sensitive and they require that those data be posted on their end. I can do this in web and I get redirected to their page with the form to fill up the card details being successfully rendered and with the data I posted but I'm not sure how to this in the mobile application itself. Please help. No hate. Thank you.

It's actually as simple as this:

payment.html

```
<form name="add-credit-card-form" id="add-credit-card-form" method="post" action="{{ postURL }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentrequest" id="paymentrequest" value="hello">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

payment.js

```
// blocks of code that allows this code to be executed
$('#add-credit-card-form').submit();
```

Comment: This is a very broad question - can you show code? You have to first decide whether you are going to go from your client to their server or whether your client is going to go to your server which then relays the request to their server.

Comment: Hi @MichelFloyd I updated the post I hope it would help. What I do is I fire the submit through jQuery and then I get redirected to the frontend page to fill up my card details. It happens on the web but not when it's already a mobile app.

Comment: There's no API for you to POST the credit card info?

Comment: That's the problem @MichelFloyd. They only have a URL that redirects you to their frontend which you will then fill up with your credit card details and not on a backend API because for them the data are sensitive and it would be best that they handle it. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: Have considered putting their frontend in an iframe?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I was also thinking about that but I'm not sure how to achieve that. Any tips to share? :)

Comment: `<iframe src='https://paymentprovider.com/foo'>`

Comment: @MichelFloyd posting the form and then targeting the frame as a source works on web but still not when it's a mobile app.. I tried adding the url in my broweser policy and in my mobile-config App.accessRule but it still won't work..

Comment: Have you asked the payment provider for help?